# find in windows (batch files)

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-excel, batch, find

Does the `find` command in windows (command line) work to search **inside** of excel files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If the text is saved as plaintext in the save file, it will come up in results for find.

Tested on windows7;

```
Made new "hello.xls" in C:\test, opened in Excel 2007, saved "foo" in cell A1

Opened command window;
c:\test>find "foo" hello.xls
```

Results

```
---------- C:\TEST\HELLO.XLS
foo
```

Comment: Won't work for the Office Open XML format, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced several times that Find command does not provide all the results. So I prefer to use the wonderful Agent Ransack utility.